# parts per million offset

Tags: calculus

> If the maximum allowable deviation from a frequencyset to be (60 GHz) is 20 parts per million (ppm). Then what is the deviation in Hz?

My solution:

$\frac{20}{1000000}* 60 *10^6 = \pm 1200 Hz$

But the right answer is $\pm 3024 Hz$. Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Believing the book?